# INDEX Altirnative when using ArrayFurmula

Tags: google-sheets

I know you're tired of reading the same line but here it is anyway:
What I'm trying to do is make a Dynamic/Dependent Dropdown List without Using Apps Scripts.

Just to keep it short with an example, `B2` Cell has a dropdown from range `V2:Y2` and that range changes dependant on `A2` Value.

[image]

We can make the values in the range `V2:Y2` change based on the value of `A2` using the formula

```
=IF(
    ISBLANK(A2), 
    , 
    TRANSPOSE(
        INDEX(
            $C$3:$D$6, 
            , 
            MATCH(A2,$C$2:$D$2)
        )
    )
)
```

Using the Fill Handle we can copy the formula onto every cell in `V` Column and automatically change the references appropriately.

[image]

**PROBLEM #1:**
This solution works fine BUT if any new rows are added, they won't have the Formula and it have to be added manually.

**SOLUTION #1: Using `ArrayFormula`.**
`ArrayFormula` Allows you to put your formula in One Cell and it would run and populate Multiple Cells with the Formula's Output depending on the Absolute/Non-Absolute References.

**PROBLEM #2:**
`ArrayFormula` hates certain Formulas like `INDEX` and `IFS`, so most people tend to use dirty workarounds like using `VLOOKUP`
[image]
`VLOOKUP` can do what `INDEX` can but the problem is as far as I know `VLOOKUP` cannot populate Multiple Cells like `INDEX` can.

**WORK AROUND #1: Using `HLOOKUP`.**
I know I was just talking crap about `VLOOKUP` and now I'm using its counterpart But this is *Different*, Instead of looking Vertically, it looks Horizontally **-Insert brain explosion gif here-**

I'm only using `HLOOKUP` instead of `VLOOKUP` Because my data is horizontal but the idea is the same, we can do what `INDEX` Does but only 1 Cell at a time.
So Using this formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
    IF(
        ISBLANK($A$2:$A), 
        , 
        IF(
            ISERROR(HLOOKUP($A$2:$A,$C$2:$D$6,COLUMN(O:O)-13)), 
            , 
            HLOOKUP($A$2:$A,$C$2:$D$6,COLUMN(O:O)-13))))
```

[image]

We can use the Fill Handle to copy the formula onto every cell in `2` Row and automatically change the references appropriately.

[image]

**LAST PROBLEM:**
Now we have the same problem As before but we just changed the Axis.
Ideally, I want to put one formula that can papulate cells in both Axes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this in `Cell` `O2` or `V2` perhaps and see how it goes...

```
=byrow(A2:A,lambda(z,if(z="",,transpose(filter(C3:D7,C2:D2=z)))))
```